# I don't know what's wrong when i click the button nothing work

Tags: javascript, html

```
var zer = document.getElementById("zer");

zer.addEventListener("click", function(){

document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Hello World";    
})
```

Comment: can you add the jsfiddle link for the code?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <button id="zer" >click here</button>
        <div id="info"></div>
    </div>

</body> 
</html>

Comment: its working !! https://jsfiddle.net/ahpm4k8d/1/

Comment: so the problem in html right?

Comment: try putting your script at the bottom, just below closing </body> tag.  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> <script src="script.js"></script>

Comment: oh my god it's work!!! and I thinking in it for 2 hours !!

Comment: you don't need jquery here as the code is pure js

Comment: @scraaappy it's part of jQuery & jason and that stuffs

Comment: but I faced problem in json so I back to the first step@scraaappy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you get where you were wrong.

The best practice is to keep the scripts at the end so that all the html code is loaded and then the scripts are loaded.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body> 
        <div id="container">
          <button id="zer" >click here</button>
          <div id="info"></div>
         </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
      </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: this shouldn't be the correct answer. this does not require jQuery nor does the snippet work.

Comment: @dysfunc please read the questions and comments .... you will get to know.
Don't just downvote,  i didn't added jQuery, it was added by the user.

Comment: i guess you get a pass on the `jQuery`comment since the op includes `jQuery` but doesn't use it. Your stack snippet still doesn't work.

Comment: @dysfunc okay, i am not running the script now. :) removed the jQuery also

Comment: @dysfunc I really need jQuery cuz it's just the first part of the tutrial

Comment: @LubnaNine that's totally fine. I wasn't sure if you truly needed it or not. I was simply trying to make sure the answer provided actually worked.